# Why would this assignment to a std::vector index fail?

Tags: c++, qt, c++14, stdvector, assign

I have a `class ObjectManager`, that has a member variable

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<BoardPiece>>> gameMap_;
```

as in a matrix of shared pointers to class instances of `BoardPiece`. This matrix is initialized to contain mostly `nullptr`s. Now, as the names of these variables would suggest, a player might later place a `BoardPiece` on the `gameMap_`.

However, when I try to do an assignment to the matrix, as in

```
GOManager_->getGameMap().at(unsigned(c.x())).at(unsigned(c.y()))
      = GOManager_->getTileInPlay();
```

where `c` is the coordinate of the tile on the game board, nothing happens. When I look at the debugger in QT Creator, there is still a null pointer at the location where the assignment was supposed to be made.

What might be causing an assignment to fail in a situation like this? The `BoardPiece` knows its own appearance, meaning it contains a dynamically created `QPixmap`. `BoardPiece`s have a copy constructor, though, so that shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: What is the values of `c.x()` and `c.y()`? What is the size of `gameMap_`? What is the size of `gameMap_[c.x()]`? And what does `getGameMap` return, `gameMap_` by reference or ***by value***?

Comment: Ah, that might be it. `GameObjectManager::getGameMap`  might indeed be copying the `gameMap`, instead of returning a reference to an existing one.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the tile not being placed into the matrix was indeed the fact, that I wasn't returning a reference to the gameMap, but a copy of said container.